# Difference output for "" and " " in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have tried 2 conditions in JavaScript and output:

```js
if(""){console.log("Called")} //No Output

if("_"){console.log("Called")} //Output: Called
```

What could be the possible reason for this?

Comment: Empty string is a falsey value.

Answer (score 2):

The empty string is considered as a '[falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)' value, and so it's equivalent to doing:

```
if(false){console.log("Called")}
```

Answer (score 0):

The empty string is equal to False if you cast it to Boolean ([Type Conversion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_Conversion)).

```
console.log(Boolean("")) //output: false
console.log(Boolean("somestring")) //output: true
```